# How to get JS fiddle to work with simple width and height percentages

Tags: css, jsfiddle

I'm trying to post a problem I ran into with percentages and I'm having a lot of trouble reducing it to the simplicist case in JS fiddle. I don't want to have to extrapolate too much from the issue but JS fiddle is forcing me to.

css:

```
.content-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   outline: 1px solid;
}

.inner-box {
   width: 56%;
   height: 56%;
   position: relative;
   outline: 1px solid;
}
```

html:

```
<div class = "content-container">  
    <div class = "inner-box">

    </div>
</div>
```

js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XMBEq/1/

the exact same code.

http://bonkmas.com/examplejs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need -

```
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XMBEq/2/)